# Find top most ancestor of nodes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I've come across this problem before, say with Categories or Tags.
You have multiple tags that can be children of each other:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Sports', parent_id: null }
{ id: 2, name: 'Fruits', parent_id: null }
{ id: 3, name: 'Citrus', parent_id: 2 }
{ id: 4, name: 'Orange', parent_id: 3 }
{ id: 5, name: 'Hockey', parent_id: 1 }
```

Another representation of these nodes:

```
Sports -> Hockey
Fruits -> Citrius -> Orange
```

What is the algorithm that efficiently finds the top-most parent for each node? So we can go from Orange -> Fruits in O(1) time.

(Requires some preprocessing).

Comment: You're looking for a [union-find structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) which does this in linear time

Answer (score 1):

As another answer suggests, you could first create a dictionary keyed by node id. But then when finding the top-level parent of a node, that information should bubble up from recursion and be used to update all intermediate nodes, since they have the same top-level parent. This will save on the work to do and make the whole proces O(n).

```js
const categories = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Sports', parent_id: null },
    { id: 2, name: 'Fruits', parent_id: null },
    { id: 3, name: 'Citrus', parent_id: 2 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Orange', parent_id: 3 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Hockey', parent_id: 1 },
    { id: 6, name: 'Apple', parent_id: 2 }
];

// Build a Map of nodes keyed by node id:
const map = new Map(categories.map(node => [node.id, node]));

// Enrich each node with parent and top node-references
function extendNode(node) {
    if (!node.top) {
        node.parent = map.get(node.parent_id);
        node.top = node.parent ? extendNode(node.parent) : node;
    }
    return node.top;
}
categories.forEach(extendNode);

// Example use:
const orange = map.get(4);
console.log(orange.name, "=>", orange.top.name);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Idea:

1. First create a dictionary for each id that takes `O(n)` where `n` is the length of `categories` array.
2. Traverse each array element and look for its top parent so it takes `O(n*d)` where `d` is the depth of its parent and build a dictionary that contains keys as child names and values as parent properties.

So this approach takes `O(n*d)` for preprocessing.

But if you use **DP** for `getParent()` the time complexity would be `O(n*α)` where `α` is a slowly growing function. so it's not exactly `O(n)` but pretty close to the linear runtime.

### Idea of DP in details:

We can also reduce the computations of `getParent()` by using **Dynamic programming**. For example, look at this dependency path `Fruits -> Citrius -> Orange` so when we visit `Citrius` we know that ends up in `Fruits` so we need to **memoize** the result. so when next time when we start from `Orange` the next node is `Citrius` and we know from `Citrius` we can have the result `Fruits`. So no need to visit all nodes.

```js
const categories = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Sports', parent_id: null },
{ id: 2, name: 'Fruits', parent_id: null },
{ id: 3, name: 'Citrus', parent_id: 2 },
{ id: 4, name: 'Orange', parent_id: 3 },
{ id: 5, name: 'Hockey', parent_id: 1 },
{ id: 6, name: 'Apple', parent_id: 2 }
];

//Build a dictionary for each id so we can look up its parent efficiently while traversing
const refDict = categories.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc,
  [item.id]: item
}), {});

//it looks for its parent
const getParent = (id) => {
  const child = refDict[id];
  if (child.parent_id === null) return { ...child
  };
  return getParent(child.parent_id);
}

//final dict which contains keys as the name of every child and value as its parent's properties
//So we can look at any topmost parent in constant time
const finalDict = categories.reduce((acc, item) => (item.parent_id === null ? { ...acc
} : { ...acc,
  [item.name]: getParent(item.id)
}), {});

console.log(finalDict);
console.log("parent - ", finalDict["Orange"]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Hope it helps!